# Autoplay embedded Youtube video with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, replace, youtube, fancybox

I have on my page a linked image which when clicked loads up a **Fancybox** modal box. It does this successfully but I want the video to **autoplay**. If I set the YouTube URL to `autoplay=1`, the hidden DIV plays in the background on page load.

```
// Here is the linked image
<a id="inline" href="#video"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="Description" /></a>

// Here is the hidden DIV
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="video">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="###YOUTUBE LINK###rel=0&amp;hd=1&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

// Here is the script
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
  });
</script>
```

My guess is I need to do some sort of **Bind()** event and string replace to change `autoplay=0` to `autoplay=1` but I have tried a few variations without any success

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First change the `href` of your linked image to your YouTube URL making sure "`autoplay=1`" [like this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sw0ihnuvIKI&autoplay=1) (NOT the embed URL). Then get rid of your hidden `<div>` and [follow tip 4 on the FancyBox "Tips & Tricks" page](http://fancybox.net/blog#tip4) which is fairly straight forward:

```
$("#tip4").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

- [Quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/5QZsG/1/)

Doing it this way, people still get to watch the video, even if JS is disabled for them.

Comment: I had tried something similar based on Tip #4, but it just loads a Fancybox modal box with nothing in it. Right-clicking in the area says "Movie not loaded"

Comment: Ah OK fixed it. You just need the normal URL for the above to work, not the embedded link. All solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to figure that out too first time around.